# where are python packages installed on Lion?

Tags: python

I'm pretty sure before Lion, I was using `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Although this might have been from a manual install of 2.7 on 10.6 OS X.

Anyway, any idea where standard location is for python packages that are installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/Library/Python/x.x/site-packages
```

(x.x designates the version).

Comment: I'm not seeing the site-packages folder anymore in there though.. For instance, I have django installed, but can't find it's source files

Comment: nevermind, figured it out (/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages)

Answer (score 1):

Found it! Python packages are installed in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` by default.

Answer (score 1):

Answers are correct for the default OSX install of Python.   If you have been mucking about trying different versions and changing paths you might be using a different one.   If you are struggling with not being able to import packages that you installed.   Try:

```
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
print(get_python_lib())
```